# Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): Failure writing output to destination

Tags: r, amazon-s3

Hi I am trying to read csv file data from S3 using R. (28G data, using m5.24xlarge cluster with 348G memory) But met error:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): Failure writing output to destination
Traceback:

1. s3read_using(FUN = read.csv, object = "s3://communication-attribution/test_data/uidisplayemailopenformatteddata/part-00000-84c15b36-9cfa-4944-91e6-fb35145c6f09-c000.csv")
2. save_object(bucket = bucket, object = object, file = tmp)
3. s3HTTP(verb = "GET", bucket = bucket, path = paste0("/", object),
   .     headers = headers, write_disk = httr::write_disk(path = file,
   .         overwrite = overwrite), ...)
4. httr::GET(url, H, query = query, write_disk, show_progress, ...)
5. request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
6. request_fetch(req$output, req$url, handle)
7. request_fetch.write_disk(req$output, req$url, handle)
8. curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle)

Here is my code:

`dfsmall <- s3read_using(FUN = read.csv, object = "s3://communication-attribution/test_data/uidisplayemailopenformatteddata/part-00000-84c15b36-9cfa-4944-91e6-fb35145c6f09-c000.csv")`

Comment: No mention of time-out, but this would help diagnose [curl time out](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/72), you do have write permission where you're writing?

Comment: yes. I have writing permission. As once I change to another smaller file, it worked.

Comment: A size limit is being imposed somewhere, and given size seems you want [aws s3 MultiPart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125125/can-i-resume-a-download-from-aws-s3), rather than `read.csv` over curl.

Comment: Having the same problem using `fread` with a large CSV on S3...